# Magento 1.8 admin not able to upload images

Tags: magento

I got hacker attacked recently due to shoplift vulnerability. After applied all patches (including the latest one) and changed all passwords, web is working now. But I found all images of all products are gone/disappeared as well as "browser" and "upload" button in product image upload page when I logged in as admin, see a warning like "Image type and information need to be specified for each store view". 
However, all uploaded images are good to see from frontend.
I have my permission set as below:

```
find . -type f \-exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d \-exec chmod 755 {} \;

find media/ -type f \-exec chmod 664 {} \;
find media/ -type d \-exec chmod 775 {} \;
find var/ -type f \-exec chmod 664 {} \;
find var/ -type d \-exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

I am not sure if this is some thing left by hacker and need a housekeeping or somewhere I did wrong....

Would anyone help to address...Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you have latest version of Flash player installed on your system?

Comment: Yes, I have latest Flash player installed. Anyway, I thought Magento should have nothing to do with Flash Player...